# Get Random Days Based on the Month in R

Tags: r, date, sample

I want to be able to generate random YYYMMDD variables

I tried:

```
Day=ifelse(substr(o1$Month,6,7) %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,10,12),sample(c(paste0('0',1:9),10:31),1),
           ifelse(substr(o1$Month,6,7) == 2,sample(c(paste0('0',1:9),10:28),1),sample(c(paste0('0',1:9),10:30),1)))
```

to generate a random day based on the month. Note that `o1$Month` is of YYYY-MM format. But the results are all identical days.

```
> table(o1$Day)
```

25

55

Can anyone offer some advice so I can get other days as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a random date you could use the following:

```
gsub("-", "", sample(seq(as.Date("1900-01-01"), 
                         as.Date("2000-12-31"), 
                         by = "day"), 10))

#[1] "19700214" "19910824" "19640205" "19531101" "19020116" "19360823" "19791019" "19520713" "19890408" "19220327"
```

Here, I create a sequence of days between two dates (1900/01/01 and 2000/12/31) and then randomly sample from them 10 times. If you want unique dates, use this code. Otherwise, set `replace = TRUE` in the `sample` function. I then use `gsub` to replace the dashes with empty strings. For example, `1947-11-01` becomes `19471101`. You can change the dates to sample from if you want a specific range.

Comment: love it, nice and simple